# Handling Errors in a plotting function

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have a shiny application which takes an input of a csv file.

I have a plotting function in `server.R`

`myPlot <- function(data)`{This function uses the variables from the data frame in parenthesis. This data frame is the input from the uploaded file.}

Imagine if the data frame does not have the columns which are used by the function we will encounter an error in the shiny tab.

How does one handle such an error?

I would like to handle it by throwing a message stating "the following file is not compatible."

Comment: You can use `validate()` and `need()`: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html

Comment: wont work as validate and need will check inputs
but in this case we need to apply the uploaded file to the plotting function.

Comment: tryCatch(myplot(ss),error = function(e){print("Did it")},warning = function(e){print("Did it")})

Did the following works for most errors.
However it does not handle facet_wrap
getting 
Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
How do I handle this?
Need a robust error handler for plots

Answer (score 0):

It is just as @UnnamedUser suggested, you can use the `validate()` and `need()` functions to check conditions:

Example: I am trying to plot `data$Col_A` and `data$Col_B`. The plot only renders if both columns are in the data.frame, otherwise it shows a predefined error message.

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(
  Col_A = 1:5,
  Col_D = 16:20)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(
        sum(c("Col_A", "Col_B") %in% colnames(data)) == 2, "Col_A and/or Col_B columns are missing!")
    )
    plot(data$Col_A, data$Col_B)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```